# My AndroidManifest.xml is full of errors, why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make my first app in Android Studio. I tried to write something on my  AndroidManifest.xml that didn't work, so I deleted it again. But now my AndroidManifest.xml is full of errors and I cant run my app. I have no idea whats wrong. I dont know so much about coding. I hope someone can help me. My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.bobbysmedicin">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Remove this (space or tab), then try to run your app

Comment: When i try to run it it say: Error running 'app': Default Activity not found

Comment: You've got a surplus "/" after "landscape". This means you've terminated the <activity> section prematurely. As @FrederikMikkelsen notes, the extra space at the start of the <xml> line will also probably upset the XML parser. Does Android Studio not warn about XML errors like this?

Comment: It was the surplus after "landscape" that was the problem. Now everything is fine. Thank you very much ! :)